# ViewWillTransitionToSize don't works if used in two classes

Tags: ios, swift, viewwilltransitiontosize

I want to detect the orientation change in different ViewControllers. I used this code

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
      print("roration detected- ViewController 1")
    }
```

It worked fine until I added this code in another ViewController. Now the function is executed only in the second ViewController. If I deleted from there than it start working in the first ViewController again. Do you have an idea what the problem is?

Comment: How are the two view controllers connected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try to call `super` method:

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransitionToSize(size, withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator)
    print("rotation detected- ViewController 1")
}
```